# iPhone SDK: UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I'm working on an app that uses a UIWebView to display its help files. The webView lives in it's own view, DocViewController...when its called the

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
```

method uses

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:docPage ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

to load the proper doc page.  However, once the first page is loaded, the view becomes static and new pages aren't loaded when the docPage changes and the view is toggled. Is there a way to clear the webView so new pages load when requested?

Edit:
The first answer is confusing to me. As is the routine below works. It's just that it only works *once*. After the view is loaded the first time it does not change when this view is toggled on again and the requested html page is different. The view always displays the first html page requested and will not load new requests.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

     docPage = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", hexpage];

     [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:docPage ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];

 }
```

Comment: Are you loading the new requests programatically or do they originate from interaction within the web view, i.e. tapping hyperlinks. If it's the latter there might be a problem with your paths, therefor the use of baseURL to tell the webview where your web root is

Comment: No interaction, it's all programmed. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is only called once, unless the view is released and needs to be reloaded.  This occurs usually only when the view controller receives a low memory warning.  Instead of `viewDidLoad`, try putting that code in `viewWillAppear:`, which gets called every time the view will show on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

passing an NSURL object to the dir that contains your HTML as baseURL and loading the HTML string with something like

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfile" 
                                                 ofType:@"html"];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path 
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                              error:nil];
```

Edit:
Also, make sure that your hyperlinks are not trying to open in a new window with something like target="_blank", your webview will not open those