# Using directory with WebViewUI

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I've got 60 or so web pages that I'd like to put into a directory. How can I modify this `webview loadrequest` to pull content from a directory?

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:docPage ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632520/iphone-sdk-uiwebview/632600#632600

Comment: I was hoping for something a little simpler. That code confused me when I first saw it. Can I not modify  [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:docPage ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
 which works, cramming in path info?